# Cutting a cake into 7 pieces with 3 straight cuts - NO 3D

Tags: geometry

We want to have 7 pieces by only cutting our tasty cake with three straight and vertical cuts (maybe done with a katana :D),

> I dont require to have all the pieces of the same size.

*Sorry if it's repeated, but I couldnt find it here.*

*Very similar to [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/cutting-a-cake-into-8-pieces), but in this case we can not rely on the fact of making 3D cuts. All the cuts must be vertical.*

> THANKS TO @n00b, "Apparently there is a name for this type of puzzle; en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence"

Comment: Given the answer is fairly easy, it could be a new puzzle to figure out of there is a way to make 7 cuts EXACTLY the same size, if you are not allowed to mesure distances or angles (well, other then using a drawing compass). Not sure if it has an answer though.

Comment: David, remember to choose the *Best Answer* when you think a question you'd made had been answered. You can do that by clicking in the *tick* nexto to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there is a name for this type of puzzle;  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Sorry, I pressed but seems it didnt accept the answer.

Comment: @n00b WOW!!!! wanted to +1 you but I couldnt!! Really good appreciation, will add it in the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's some tasty cake right here. I want the middle piece.

> [image: Tasty]

Comment: not even 5 min hahahaha :(. Congrats

Comment: You want that tiny piece in the middle? Okay, I'll take the larger ones from the side :)

Answer (score 6):

> Cut the cake into 4 pieces with two perpendicular cuts, meeting at the center. Move the slices so they line up, then slice once more down the middle. Eat one piece and now you have 7 pieces.